# Xamarin Forms Cannot create a user control with two way binding to view model property names

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

My objective is to create a user control containing a basic Entry control that will update a specified property in my view model.
 I have been unable to bind the user control to the property name in my view model unless the view model property name is exactly the same as the property in the user control. This defeats the purpose of a reusable two way reusable control.
 I suspect I'm just missing a key concept.

My expectation is that I should be able to add one or more of my UserEditors to a page and bind it to various string properties in the view model, and the property the UserEditor gets/sets should be the property I specify in the {Binding } for the UserEditor.

I have created a simple PCL project to test with. I would be very grateful if someone can get me on the correct track with this. I have exhausted all other resources to come to grips with this. I can provide a zip file of the VS2015 solution, however its pretty big (65MB) with all the XAM stuff.

Here are all the pieces:

UserEditor.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             x:Class="UserControl.UserEditor">
  <ContentView.Content>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,0,10" >
            <Entry x:Name="TextEntry" 
                   Text="{Binding Text}"
                   HorizontalOptions="Fill"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

UserEditor.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace UserControl
{
    public partial class UserEditor : ContentView
    {
        //Bindable property for Text
        public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("Text",
                typeof(string),
                typeof(UserEditor),
                string.Empty,
                BindingMode.TwoWay,
                null,
                OnTextPropertyChanged,
                null,
                null,
                null);

        public static void OnTextPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            var control = bindable as UserEditor;
            if (control == null) return;
            control.TextEntry.Text = newValue.ToString();
        }

        public UserEditor()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string Text
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)GetValue(TextProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(TextProperty, value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MainPageViewModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;

namespace UserControl
{
class MainPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged

{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public MainPageViewModel()
    {

    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

    string textProperyInVM = "Initial value";
    public string TextPropertyInVm
    {
        get
        {
            return textProperyInVM;
        }
        set
        {
            textProperyInVM = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("TextPropertyInVm");

        }
    }
}
```

}

MainPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UserControl"
         x:Class="UserControl.MainPage">

<!--//Page binding context is set to the view model in the page contructor.-->
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
<Label Text="Binding viewmodel properties to user control"  />
    <!--//Label is bound to ViewModel field named TextPropertyInVm-->
    <Label Text="{Binding TextPropertyInVm}" ></Label>

    <!--//UserEditor custom control is bound to ViewModel field named TextPropertyInVm
    //User editor will not see the view model property.
    //User editor ALWAYS wants to work with a property named "Text"
    //User editor neither reads nor updates the view model property specified in the Binding -->
    <!--
    Text changes in the user control cause this error:
    [0:] Binding: 'Text' property not found on 'UserControl.MainPageViewModel', target property: 'Xamarin.Forms.Entry.Text'
    -->
    <local:UserEditor Text="{Binding TextPropertyInVm, Mode=TwoWay}">  </local:UserEditor>
</StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace UserControl
{
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    private MainPageViewModel vm;
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //instantiate and bind this page to a new view model.
        vm = new MainPageViewModel();
        this.BindingContext = vm;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDITED**

There are two problems:

1. in MainPage.xaml, you have a typo: TextPropertyInVM instead of TextPropertyInVm in the UserEditor Binding.
2. You need to set the BindingContext on the TextEntry in the UserEditor constructor so the XAML know the object to bind to:

   public UserEditor()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       TextEntry.BindingContext = this;
   }

Anytime you want to use Binding, you need to make sure the BindingContext is set properly at the correct scope.

The BindingContext of the UserEditor itself is used to resolve the Binding expressions when it's used in MainPage (that was a mistake in the original version of the answer).  However the Binding expression in UserEntry.xaml itself needs to see the context of the UserEntry class, not the view model (or whatever BindingContext it inherits from the page it's in).  So the BindingContext needs to be set at some scope inside UserEntry that will affect the Entry element.

Comment: Typo fixed (casing problem), however this does't resolve the issue.

Comment: This does't resolve the issue.  The binding context is inherited from the page, so UserEditor does have correct context.  I tried setting binding context in user editor constructor, but that makes binding context user editor rather than the view model..  

Note the error in output window of VS2015: 
Binding: 'Text' property not found on 'UserControl.MainPageViewModel', target property: 'Xamarin.Forms.Entry.Text

UserEditor has the correct binding context, but is looking for the Wrong property name IE: Text instead of TextPropertyInVm

Comment: Appreciate your time.  I'm not clear on where or how I would set that binding context and I'm not sure that's the issue.  From the debug output it appears that UserEditor does have the correct context.  Here's an important point: If I add a property to the viewmodel named Text, everything works with the newly added Text property.  This seems to imply the binding context setup is in fact correct. The fundamental issue is that the  property name specified in the binding in MainPage.xaml is TextPropertyInVm rather than Text. UserEditor insists on always using a property named Text.

Comment: If another Entry in MainPage is added to modify the TextPropertyInVm the changes are seen in UserEditor. This seems to further indicate binding context to viewmodel is correct. Simple Labels in UserEdit work as expected, properly binding to whatever property name I want in the viewmodel.

Comment: The fundamental issue is that the actual property name specified in the binding in MainPage.xaml (TextPropertyInVm) is ignored and UserEditor insists on always expecting a property named Text.  Would love to see someone replicate this problem and help find the solution using the code blocks already provided OR I'd be happy to share the full VS2015 solution in a zip file.

Comment: I did replicate the problem you saw using the code you posted, The exact changes I suggested above (in the edited answer) fixed it for me. Did they not resolve it for you?

Comment: YES - I missed your edit.  Your solution is perfect.  Need to add TextEntry.BindingContext = this; in the constructor of UserEditor.cs as you indicated and all is good now.  I cannot express my thanks enough for your assistance.